# Return all matching values to a listbox upon combo box selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a form with a `ListBox` and a bunch of `TextBox`s for editing records. I also have a `ComboBox` to pick types of `trip`s from (this is defined within the form).

```
    private void LoadExpenseList()
        {
            tripSelect.Items.Clear();
            var dateSorted =
                from e in roster
                orderby e.Trip
                select e;
            foreach (var e in dateSorted)
                tripSelect.Items.Add(e.Trip);
        }

private void tripSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedExpense = (ExpenseItem)roster.TripFind((string)tripSelect.SelectedItem);
            listExpenses.Items.Add(selectedExpense);
        }


 private void listExpenses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}
```

Now, when I select a `trip` I get just the first result passed along to the `ListBox` and here's why (this is defined in the list class)

```
public ExpenseItem TripFind(string trip)
    {
        var specificExpenseItem =
           from e in this
           where e.Trip == trip
           select e;
        if (specificExpenseItem.Count() >= 1)
            return specificExpenseItem.First();
        return null;
    }
```

I keep getting problems every time I try to rewrite it! I'm getting `not all paths return a value` or the JIT debugger telling me I can't get past this.

Here's the last thing I've tried:

```
public ExpenseItem TripFind(string trip)
    {
        var specificExpenseItem =
           from e in this
           where e.Trip == trip
           select e;
        foreach (var e in specificExpenseItem);
        return null;
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all that with

```
return this.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Trip == trip);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can avoid only returning the first or default value? I want to return all of them.

Comment: In other words, you want to return an `IEnumerable<T>`.  Call `Where()` instead.

Comment: Now I'm getting this bad boy...

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Payroll.ExpenseItem>' to 'Payroll.ExpenseItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)

Comment: You need to change the return type of the method.